# How to create xml file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I need to make xml file which looks like this:

```
> <message xmlns="client"
> from="from_user" to="To_user"
> type="chat"><properties
> xmlns="@"http://software""><property><name>assetId</name><value
> type="string">5346879f73322e08db030000</value></property><property><name>status</name><value
> type="string">success</value></property><property><name>long</name><value
> type="double">22.3451</value></property>
> <property><name>lan</name><value type="double">3456</value></property>
> </properties></message>
```

I don't know how to do it. Could you help me?

Comment: Just look it up on google, then come back when you'll have some coding done and a specific problem.

Comment: What have you tried so solve this issue your self? As you question stands now it look like a code request which is really frowned upon.

Comment: This guy apparently does not know anything about XML and related technologies. It would be better to give him a link.

Comment: you don't know how to paste above code in a NotePad and Save as .xml?

Comment: you have tagged this with iOS and objective-c are you trying to create this xml in an iOS app as you don't mention this in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create it in Notepad or learn XSD and generate it.

Check this
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.ASP

and when you are done, learn this:
http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/

Answer (score 0):

you may Create it this way

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:@"<message xmlns=\"client\"from=\"from_user\" to=\"To_user\" type=\"chat\"><properties xmlns=\"@\"http://software\"\"><property><name>assetId</name><value type=\"string\">5346879f73322e08db030000</value></property><property><name>status</name><value type=\"string\">success</value></property><property><name>long</name><value type=\"double\">22.3451</value></property> <property><name>lan</name><value type=\"double\">3456</value></property> </properties></message>"];
```